# importing prototype.js library in iframe causes memory leak in IE10 32bit

Tags: javascript, iframe, memory-leaks, prototypejs, internet-explorer-10

Shortly: if page contains iframe which imports 'prototype.js' library then memory usage in browser Internet Explorer 10 x86 (not x64) increases about 0.8MB per each page load.

Detaily:

As example, we have page named "test_preview.html" which imports prototype.js library. And we have another page "test_main.html" which opens/refreshes "test_preview.html" by clicking "Refresh" button.

test_preview.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html">
<html>
<head>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.2.0/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
TEST
</body>
</html>
```

test_main.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="previewPane"></iframe>
    <button onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('previewPane').src='test_preview.html' ">Refresh</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, if I click "Refresh" button ~100 times then the memory usage of 'iexplore.exe' process increases permanently from 27MB to 138MB.

Note that I can reproduce the problem only using 32 bit version of Internet Explorer 10 (probably it is reproducible on 32bit varsion of IE11). But I can't reproduce this leak using IE10 x64 and other browsers like Chome and Firefox 29.

Do anybody know about this problem? Is it a bug in 'prototype.js' library or this is memory leak in 32bit IE10? Or this is not a bug?

Comment: I'm getting my IE 10 VM running to try and replicate this - I'll post an answer with my results

Comment: Running Win7 32bit IE 10 with all updates, I can't replicate your problem with any javascript library in the preview HTML. The highest the memory usage gets is to 33 MB and when I stop clicking Refresh the memory returns to normal.